# Which axioms of Zermelo set theory fail for $U$, and how can we prove this?

Tags: set-theory

By the phrase "$O$ is an outer model of M" let us mean that $M$ is an inner model of $O,$ according to $O$. So in particular, they have the same ordinals. Now I learned from Andres [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/817917/is-every-set-countable-according-to-some-outer-model) that:

> **Theorem.** If $M$ is a countable transitive model of $\mathrm{ZFC}$ and $x \in M$, then there is an outer model $O$ of $M$ such that $O$ believes that $x$ is countable.

This has the following interesting corollary. Let $M$ denote a countable transitive model of $\mathrm{ZFC}.$ Then the union of the set of all outer models of $M$ is not itself a model of $\mathrm{ZFC},$ nor even (I think) a model of Zermelo set theory. We argue by contradiction; suppose it was a model of Zermelo set theory, call this model $U$. Then $\aleph_1^U$ is uncountable according to $U$, and therefore it is uncountable according to every outer model of $M$. But this contradicts the above theorem

So I'm trying to puzzle out which axiom(s) $U$ fails to satisfy. It seems clear that extensionality, union, and infinity hold in $U$. So I'm thinking that either powerset fails, or that certain instances of separation fail. (With input from Asaf): perhaps pairing even fails.

> **Question.** Which axioms of Zermelo set theory fail for $U$, and how can we prove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $x\in M$ then there is a model $M_1$ in with $x$ countable. Then there is some $M_2$ in which $\omega_1^{M_1}$ is countable, and so on.

It turns out that the union doesn't have $\aleph_1$ at all. In fact, there is no continuum in $U$, since if $x\in U$ then there is some $N$ such that $M\cup\{x\}\subseteq N$, and therefore there is an extension of $N$ in which $x$ is countable.

So indeed power set fails. Pretty badly too.

Comment: Can we even be sure that $U$ satisfies the axiom of pairing? It suffices to prove that if $A$ and $B$ are outer models of a c.t.m. $M,$ then there exists $O$ that is an outer model of both $A$ and $B.$ But its not clear to me why such an $O$ ought to exist.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't have to. Here's an example (whose details, unfortunately are sort of a blackbox for me at the moment). If $M$ is a c.t.m then there are two $M$-Cohen generic reals $x,y$ such that $M[x,y]$ includes an enumeration of itself. Both $M[x]$ and $M[y]$ are subsets of $U$, but $\{x,y\}$ doesn't have to be (e.g. if $\mathsf{Ord}^U=\mathsf{Ord}^M$ which is also consistent). But I never took pairing to be an actual axiom, just a theorem (replacement + power set).

Comment: Waiting, pairing follows from replacement if we can show the existence of $2 = \{0,1\}$ or any other set with two elements, right? So if you're right that $U$ needn't satisfy pairing, then $U$ needn't satisfy replacement, either.

Comment: By the way, according to my intended definitions, $O$ is an outer model of $M$ iff $M$ is an inner model of $O$ according to $O$. So they enjoy the same ordinals, hence $\mathsf{Ord}^U = \mathsf{Ord}^M$. Is this terminology not standard?

Comment: Since replacement is not a part of Zermelo's set theory, I wouldn't worry about it either. Your intended definition is fine, but you didn't specify exactly what you had meant. Suppose that there two different heights of countable transitive models, $\alpha<\beta$. Then $L_\alpha\in L_\beta$ and $L_\beta$ knows that $L_\alpha$ is countable. In particular $L_\beta\subseteq U$ since it knows that every element in $L_\alpha$ is countable. If you want to limit yourself to the case where all the models have the same ordinals, perhaps it's good to specify that (my answer remains the same, though).

Comment: Thanks, I added your suggested clarification to the start of the question. But, I don't really get your answer. How does $\aleph_1$ not existing in $U$ (which makes perfect sense, in fact its the whole reason I find the situation so interesting) imply that powerset must fail?

Comment: @user18921: Well, now that you have that $U$ and $M$ have the same ordinals it's even easier. $U\models\forall x(|x|\leq\aleph_0)$.

Comment: But why can't every $x$ nonetheless have a powerset, while also being countable? Okay Cantor's theorem, but unless we can show that $U$ satisfies separation or at least some fragment thereof, I don't think Cantor's theorem "goes through."

Comment: You can prove directly here in this case, that there is no power set to $\omega$ there. If there were, it was countable in $U$, and there was an enumeration of it. Use it to produce a subset of $\omega$ which is not in $U$. You only need induction up to $\omega$ for this definition.

Comment: Okay, let me chew on that for a bit.

Comment: Ahh I think I get it. **Proposition.** No infinite $x \in U$ has a powerset in $U$. *Proof.* Suppose it did, call it $y$. Now $x$ and $y$ are both countable in $U$, hence they're in bijection. Let $f$ denote any such bijection. This bijection must live in some outer model $O$. So $x,y,f \in O$. Now $f$ remains a bijection between $x$ and $y$ in $O.$ Furthermore, $y$ is still the powerset of $x$ in $O$. But this contradicts Cantor's theorem.

Comment: @user18921: That also works.

Comment: So what precisely does your proof by Cohen reals show? Is it really that for *any* c.t. model $M$ we can find outer models $A$ and $B$ such that no $O$ is an outer model of both $A$ and $B$? Or is it just that for *certain* c.t. models $M$ this occurs? Can we rectify the problem by, say, assuming that $M$ satisfies $V=L$?

Comment: The former. There could be incompatible models. The $V=L$ was a different example of a model when you permit new ordinals, then there is a model which knows about the countability of $M$.

Comment: Sorry, the word "could" in the phrase "there **could** be incompatible models" is confusing to me. I think you're saying "The former; there will **always** be incompatible outer models, for any c.t model $M$." Is that right?

Comment: Yes, I'm just feeling a bit uncomfortable talking about an example whose details I've never fully seen. :-)

Comment: Yep fair enough, maybe I will ask another question to get more details and/or explanation. Thanks for answering, though.

Comment: By the way, I find it deeply unsettling that $U$ fails to satisfy pairing, and therefore must also fail to satisfy $\mathrm{ZFC}^{-}$, by which I mean $\mathrm{ZFC}$ without powerset ("done right" see e.g. [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.2430)). At the risk of being melodramatic, its as if the *true* universe (by which I mean the union of all the outer models) doesn't have enough sets. Lol, what? Huge "who ordered that" moment, a la I. I. Rabi's quote about the [muon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muon#History). This is going to bug me for awhile, methinks.

Comment: I think that you're just looking at it wrong. If there is a true universe it's most likely not the union of all generic extensions of an inner model; or even the union of other non-ordinal-adding extensions. If anything, I'd bet my money on what happens when you have plenty of countable transitive models, of many different heights, shapes and so on. Consider the following axiom "Every real number is an element of a countable transitive model". Or even every $x\in H(\omega_1)$ is a member of a countable transitive model. This sounds better.

Comment: Hey I just sent you a longish reply via email, since it didn't really fit in the comments.

Comment: Hey does the axiom "every $x \in H(\omega_1)$ is a member of a countable transitive model" have a name? I'd like to know a bit about its strength and implications.

Comment: Not that I know of. It's equivalent to the one about real numbers (because every such $x$ can be encoded in a very canonical way into a real number). (Also, I have seen your email, but haven't read it in full yet. My reply will arrive.)

Comment: No biggie about the email, I was mainly just thinking out loud. Anyway I think the two axioms you mention are very cool. Do any large cardinal axioms imply them?

Comment: Every large cardinal imply their consistency. That's for sure. If you have an uncountable transitive model which include all the real numbers, then you can prove this; and if you only have an uncountable transitive model then you can consider $L$ of that model, it is $L_\alpha$ for some $\alpha>\omega_1^L$, so in $L$ there is an uncountable transitive model including all the real numbers.

Comment: [Corrected] Cool. Also, do you know if a reflection principle holds for the elements of $H(\omega_1)$? In particular, does $\mathrm{ZFC}$ prove that if $x \in H(\omega_1)$ and $\Phi$ is a finite set of theorems of $\mathrm{ZFC}$, then we can find a countable transitive set $y$ such that $x \in y$ and $y \models \Phi$?

Comment: Yes, that's easy. You know there's a large enough $\theta$ such that $V_\theta\models\Phi$. Now take the elementary submodel generated by the transitive closure of $\{x\}$, and collapse that model (since it's well-founded), the result is a countable mode and since transitive sets don't get moved by the collapse, $x$ is in that model.

Comment: Easy for you, maybe! There's a lot I don't follow. Firstly, when we say "elementary submodel generated by $X$" where $X$ is a transitive set, do we mean the intersection of all the transitive sets $T \supseteq X$ such that $T \models \Phi$? If so, then why do we have to Mostowski collapse it? Or is it a different kind of collapse we're talking about here?

Comment: No, the Lowenheim-Skolem theorem says that given a set $A\subseteq M$ there is an elementary submodel of $M$ which includes $A$ and its size is minimal (read: $|A|\cdot\aleph_0$). Since it's a submodel of $(V_\theta,\in)$ it's well-founded. So we can collapse it. It's not the intersection of all transitive sets. It's the intersection of all submodels (transitive or otherwise). The submodel is usually not transitive, just well-founded.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I think I get it now. That's a stronger version of Lowenheim-Skolem than I'm familiar with, but it kind of makes sense though.

Comment: If you look closely, the proof of the "simpler" L-S theorem actually proves this stronger statement.